# Integer padding with something other than a zero

Tags: horizontal-alignment, siunitx, key-value

Consider the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,collcell}
\sisetup{minimum-integer-digits=4}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S}
  {Header} \\
  1234 \\ 234 \\ 34 \\ 4
\end{tabular}
%
\qquad%
%
\begin{tabular}{>{\collectcell\num}c<{\endcollectcell}}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header} \\
  1234 \\ 234 \\ 34 \\ 4
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

In the left `tabular` (the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) example), the `Header` column is centred around the "(missing) decimal point". In the right `tabular` (the [`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) example), the `Header` is centred as expected (since we're using a `c`-type column).

The integer padding in both cases produces a leading `0`. How can I modify this padding to be `\phantom{0}` (or something else altogether) so that the output resembles

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header} \\
  1234 \\ \phantom{0}234 \\ \phantom{0}\phantom{0}34 \\ \phantom{0}\phantom{0}\phantom{0}4
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I am looking for a way to add the key `integer-zero` that I can specify to my liking (default is `0`). A generalisation for `decimal-zero` (doesn't exist yet) would be equally awesome.

Comment: In essence, something has to be changed inside `\@@_number_process_integer_digits`.

Comment: So in essence `some text \num{3} and more` would be like `some text $\hphantom{000}3$ and more`. In any case, what's the use case?

Comment: @Manuel: Essentially, yes. Use case would be "discussion on padding" (so that one can represent this with another symbol, say `\cdot` or `\textvisiblespace` or `-` or ...) and perhaps for horizontal alignment in certain cases.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @JosephWright: Mainly to add another hook into the numeric manipulation/output. Also, in some cases the `S`-type columns of [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) can be inhibiting in terms of horizontal alignment. Adding this functionality allows one to use (for example) [`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) to collect a cell's contents and then process it using `\num` and all the other specifications already set using `\sisetup`.

Comment: @JosephWright: I've added an example of the use-case.

Comment: @Werner The edit is just a use of `\tablenum`, surely? (`\num` and `\tablenum` are semantically different.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the case of aligning numbers when not using a normal column situation, `siunitx` provides the `\tablenum` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,collcell}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-format = 4.0}
\begin{tabular}{>{\collectcell\tablenum}c<{\endcollectcell}}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header} \\
  1234 \\ 234 \\ 34 \\ 4
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This is specifically there for creating alignment-compatible number formatting in non-standard situations.

In the case in the question, I don't think that is really even needed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 4.0]}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header} \\
  1234 \\ 234 \\ 34 \\ 4
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay.... great! I can live with this (missed `\tablenum` as a macro in the documentation). Do you see any value for a changeable `0` in `\num` so you can also use it in inline discussions. As in "`We use \num{234}... where * denotes...`" that shows as "We use *234... where * denotes..."?

Answer (score 1):

OTOH, If you aren't married to `\num`, you could use something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
1234\\
234\\
34\\
4
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mynum}[1]{\phantom{0000}\llap{#1}}
\begin{document}
\mynum{1234}\par
\mynum{234}\par
\mynum{34}\par
\mynum{4}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but just playing around. If you don't need zeroes inside the number, then it's an answer; because it “replaces” every zero, doesn't matter if it's on the left or on the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,calc}
\sisetup{minimum-integer-digits=4}
\begin{document}
\begingroup\mathcode`\0="8000
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\0\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\makebox[\widthof{0}]
 {\textvisiblespace}}
%{$\cdot$}}
\num{1234}\par
\num{234}\par
\num{34}\par
\num{4}    
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]